# JavaScript: Optimize sorting a custom object literal

Tags: javascript, sorting, object-literal

I have an object literal as follows:

```
var obj = {
    one: "short-term",
    two: "long-term",
    three: "mid-term",
    four: "long-term",
    five: "short-term",
    six: "short-term",
    seven: "long-term",
    eight: "mid-term",
    nine: "short-term",
    ten: "mid-term"
};
```

And I would like to sort the order of the key/value pairs based on the value such that the end result would be:

```
var obj = {
    one: "short-term",
    five: "short-term",
    six: "short-term",
    nine: "short-term",
    three: "mid-term",
    eight: "mid-term",
    ten: "mid-term",
    two: "long-term",
    four: "long-term",
    seven: "long-term"
};
```

My sorting method is quite straightforward and probably inefficient (Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rxroak3k/)):

```
var sorted = {};

for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj[i] === "short-term") {
        sorted[i] = obj[i];
    }
}
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj[i] === "mid-term") {
        sorted[i] = obj[i];
    }
}
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj[i] === "long-term") {
        sorted[i] = obj[i];
    }
}
```

Is it possible for this given scenario to achieve the same result by looping through the object *only once* with or without using jQuery but no other libraries?

I have quite a few similar cases in my project where I need to employ the same sorting method and I'm afraid my current way of handling it isn't quite optimal for a large set of objects.

Comment: You cannot sort objects. The key-value pairs have no order.

Comment: @Bergi - So, what I have is as good as it gets?

Comment: Use an array instead.

Comment: What are you doing that requires this sorting? Perhaps we can suggest another way to achieve your goal

Comment: Is efficiency a requirement for your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifying your obj structure, you could do:

```
var sortedKeys=[];
for(var i in obj){
    sortedKeys.push({key:i, value:obj[i]}) // push key and value to array
}
sortedKeys.sort(function(a,b){ // sort array by value
    return a.value < b.value
})
for(var i=0;i<sortedKeys.length;i++){ // you can either use now sortedKeys or keep using obj
    console.log(obj[sortedKeys[i].key])
    console.log(sortedKeys[i].value)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Objects in Javascript are hashmaps. You shouldn't expect every interpreter - for example, browsers, if this is to run in a page - to present you the keys in the same order they were inserted.

If you need to order those, I suggest you populate an array. If you want to keep using objects, though, you could add an `order` property to each value. You could re-structure your map like this:

```
var obj = {
    one: { value: "short-term", order: 1 },
    five: { value: "short-term", order: 2 },
    /*  .. SNIP .. */
};
```

Then you can come up with a sorting mechanism, and apply that whenever you need to retrieve your values.